# React Router V4 structure

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two layouts: `MainLayout` and `EmptyLayout` for Login and SignUp component.

This is my current structure:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login">
        <EmptyLayout>
          <LogInContainer />
        </EmptyLayout>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <MainLayout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/marketing" >
              <MarketingComponent />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" >
              <DashboardContainer />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/admin/users" >
              <UsersContainer />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/admin/users/add" >
              <AddUsersContainer />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </MainLayout>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Is this a good approach?
How can I include 404 pages here?

```
<EmptyLayout>
  <NotFound />
</EmptyLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<Switch/>` component renders the first `<Route/>` that matches, and a `<Route/>` without `path` always matches, so you can simply put your 404 content inside `<Route>...</Route>` as the last child of your `<Switch/>`.

That said, RRv4 is very powerful because you can set up routes anywhere in your app, so like in Tyler's answer, you could make the `/add` part of the route be handled in your `<UsersContainer/>`. This will be even easier once [relative routes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/4539) land.